# Filtering data on form causes combo box to not function

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, filtering

I have a form that displays student records.

I have a combobox that allows you to select a student.

Finally, I have two buttons for filtering. One filters on all Students the other only active Students.

Two Issues which I beleive are related.

One, when the form loads the cbo does NOT work.

Two, if I select the "All Students" button the cbo works. When I select the "Active Students" button the cbo does NOT work again.

Form Record Source:

```
Select tblStudents.*
```

Form Load:

```
Private Sub cmdStudent_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdStudent_Click_Err

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudents", acNormal, "", "[Last3]=" & "'" & "Sanders 
862" & "'", , acNormal

cmdStudent_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

cmdStudent_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume cmdStudent_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

ComboBox Code:

```
Private Sub cboFindRecord_AfterUpdate()

' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[SN] = '" & Me![cboFindRecord] & "'"
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

All Students Button:

```
Private Sub cmdAllStudents_Click()

cmdAllStudents.ForeColor = 16777215
cmdAllStudents.BackColor = 16711680
cmdAllStudents.FontBold = True

cmdActiveStudents.ForeColor = 0
cmdActiveStudents.BackColor = 16777215
cmdActiveStudents.FontBold = False

Me.FilterOn = False

cboFindRecord.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
cboFindRecord.RowSource = "SELECT tblStudents.SN, tblStudents.Last3 FROM 
tblStudents ORDER BY tblStudents.Last3;"
cboFindRecord.Requery
Call cboFindRecord_AfterUpdate
cboFindRecord.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Active Student Button:

```
Private Sub cmdActiveStudents_Click()

cmdActiveStudents.ForeColor = 16777215
cmdActiveStudents.BackColor = 16711680
cmdActiveStudents.FontBold = True

cmdAllStudents.ForeColor = 0
cmdAllStudents.BackColor = 16777215
cmdAllStudents.FontBold = False

Me.FilterOn = True

cboFindRecord.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
cboFindRecord.RowSource = "SELECT tblStudents.SN, tblStudents.Last3, 
tblStudents.Status_ID FROM tblStudents WHERE (((tblStudents.Status_ID) Not 
In (6,7))) ORDER BY tblStudents.Last3;"
cboFindRecord.Requery
Call cboFindRecord_AfterUpdate
cboFindRecord.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Thank you for any assistance.

I have tried modifying the record set to match all or active students with no change.

Comment: Please elaborate on what happens or doesn't when the cbo doesn't work: is there an error message or is it just blank?

Comment: Also, filtering a query by a specific field doesn't require that field to be returned in the select list. Do you need the `tblStudents.Status_ID` to be returned for something else? Could returning three fields instead of two be causing the issue for the "Active Student" selection?

Comment: @Mistella There was no error message. I would select a student in the cbo and the form wouldn't refresh with that record. it would only work when I activated the button for filtering on ALL students. Then the cbo would work. The issue was coming from the action of loading the Student form from the first form and forcing the form to display my test student. Once I removed that code and moved it to the "On Load: event for the Student form all is working. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

OK, not sure why this is happening but I have fixed my issue. The problem is with the form loading code.

When I was loading the Student from from another form, I had it load our test student by default. My theory is that this was changing the record-set. I would appreciate an explanation if someone knows.

I removed forcing the student record when loading the student form and put the code in the On Load event for the form.